# How to get rows that are less than or greater than in dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a dynamic SQL where it has a information about the person, for e.g.

Table

```
ID   Name   Address  Age(int)
1    a       Main     30
2    b       CT       35
```

Now how can I get all Person their `Age < 40 or Age >= 30 or Age <= 50` etc. What I am trying to do is pass " <30 " or " >40 " etc as parameter and query accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MSSQL, you can use EXEC to achieve this indirection.  For example:

```
DECLARE @age_constraint AS VARCHAR(100) = '<30'
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(255)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Age' + @age_constraint
EXEC(@query)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using MSSQL. Here is more information.

Comment: Sorry I hit Enter key before completing my information.    - Actually DateOfBirth is in datetime and then I converted to Age as int when I executed (Cast(DATEDIFF(hour, DateOfBirth, GETDATE())/8766 as Int)'>10')
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 55
Incorrect syntax near '>10'. I got this message.

Comment: If Age is a calculated column you can still use that inside the `EXEC()` args.  You can try: 
`SET @query = 'SELECT t.*, CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, t.DateOfBirth, GETDATE())/8766 AS INT) AS Age FROM Table AS t WHERE Age ' + @age_constraint`.  
And then you can `EXEC(@query)`.  Any valid SQL can go inside the `EXEC()`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'm curious about is whether you're scripting this out yourself or if you're having a UI component do it. The main issue with the latter is that you introduce SQL injection issues if you allow users to just type in "<40" for instance.

To help prevent that and make sure your datatypes make sense for the columns you're checking, you can use sp_executesql, but you'd have to separate out your operator from your numeric value. Something along these lines should work:

```
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000), @parameterlist NVARCHAR(500), @ageParameter INT, @equality NVARCHAR(2)
    SET @ageParameter = 40
    SET @equality = '='

    SET @sql = 
        'SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE @equality = ''='' AND Age = @ageParameter
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE @equality = ''<'' AND Age < @ageParameter
        UNION ALL   
        SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE @equality = ''>'' AND Age > @ageParameter 
    '

    SET @parameterlist = '@ageParameter INT, @equality NVARCHAR(2)'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @parameterlist, @ageParameter = @ageParameter, @equality = @equality
```

More information on how sp_executesql works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I am using this script for my SSRS report. Thank you for your input.